# For two matrices A and B we say that the dimension column space of ( A + B) is less than dimension of ( column space A + column space B)

Tags: linear-algebra

While studying linear algebra I came across this statement but my doubt is at the starting part of this result where we are saying that column space of A + column space of B of is a greater set than column space of (A+B). How can we say this? Why is Vc(A+B) a subset of Vc(A)+Vc(B) ?

Answer (score 1):

Any linear combination of the columns of $A+B$ can be written as a linear combination of columns of $A$ and columns of $B$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a column in $A+B$, is a sum of columns of those in $A$ and in $B$, so the span of the columns of A and B is at least as large as the span of the columns of $A+B$.

As an example, consider $I$ and $-I$. The span of the columns of both these matrices is everything (dim 2) while the span of the sum $0$ is trivial (dim 0).